# git patch -p confusion

Tags: git

So, I try to patch my current branch using command

```
patch -p RETURN quote-patch.txt
```

However, I dont know what number should I put after -p option.I tried to put several number (0,1,2,3,4), but it return this error:

```
patching file RETURN
Hunk #1 FAILED at 74.
Hunk #2 FAILED at 84.
Hunk #3 FAILED at 95.
Hunk #4 FAILED at 107.
Hunk #5 FAILED at 139.
Hunk #6 FAILED at 187.
6 out of 6 hunks FAILED -- saving rejects to file RETURN.rej
```

any idea? thx

Comment: -1: There is not nearly enough information here to work out what's going wrong for you. Try understanding what the `-p` option actually does (run `man patch` for the help files) and then you may have a better idea of the question you need to ask.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your patch does not apply to your current working set.

Without more information, I cannot say why that is the case. Perhaps you changed `RETURN` locally before attempting the patch application. As the message suggests, try taking a look in `RETURN.rej` (and `RETURN` itself) to fix up the fallout.

When using the `patch` command-line utility, you should use a `-p` number which causes the paths in the patch to match up with those in your working set: If the patch header says `+++ lib/foo/RETURN`, and your current working directory has `foo/RETURN` in it, that would be a case for `-p1`.

However, since you've tagged this question "git", I'm going to assume you're in a git repository. When using git, you shouldn't use the `patch` tool: instead, either push+pull changes naturally, or use `git format-patch` and `git am` to send and receive sets of changes. That will preserve permissions, commit messages, authorship information, and so on. All this extra metadata would be lost if you use a straight `diff` and then apply the change with `patch`.

Comment: do you mean, I can do the same thing by using command "git format-patch (commit hash code)" and apply the change using git am?

Comment: @user1988385 "The same thing", but better. As I mentioned, `git format-patch` saves more information than `diff`, and `git am` applies more than `patch`. The command you want for just one commit which you currently have checked out is `git format-patch HEAD~`.